# bash script gives command not found error when using if statement

Tags: linux, bash, debian

I am writing a bash script which will upload certain files on my AWS(Amazon web services) bucket when the script runs.I am trying to get a confirmation from the AWS by using "if" statement in the bash script and searching for the file name that i want to confirm has been copied to the bucket.This is the code for that-

```
if [`echo $(s3cmd ls s3://my-bucket/) | grep -c "file.txt" ` -gt 0 ]
    then

    echo "Success"; 
else

    echo "fail";

fi
```

When I run this script it gives me an error

```
./myBash.sh: line 21: [1: command not found
```

It says line 21 coz there is rest of my code too (irrelevant to this part of the code coz i am just running a few echos there)

Can anyone help with this? I searched around on the net but did not find any satisfactory results.

I am running debian linux (Jesse) on my Raspberry Pi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a space after the `[`:

```
if [ `echo $(s3cmd ls s3://my-bucket/) | grep -c "file.txt" ` -gt 0 ]
```

Your backticked command expand to `1`, so right now you have

```
if [1 -gt 0 ]
```

which means the shell is trying to run `[1` as a command, and no such command exists.

Comment: Also, remove the useless `echo`.

Comment: I added the space between the [ and `echo and it worked. Thank you sir

Comment: An in fact, just use `if s3cmd ls s3://my-bucket/ | grep -q 'file\.txt'`.